# How to formally change Linux Mint KDE to Cinnamon edition?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, desktop-environment

I originally installed Mint 17.2 KDE. After some time I upgraded it to 17.3.

After yet another time, I installed Cinnamon desktop environment and [**completely purged all packages related to KDE**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/324916/126755).

Now I want to upgrade to Mint 18 Cinnamon using the `mintupgrade` utility.

```
mintupgrade check
```

says:

```
  + Checking your Linux Mint codename...

  + Checking your Linux Mint edition...

------------------------------------------------
!!  ERROR: Your edition of Linux Mint is 'KDE'. It cannot be upgraded to Linux Mint 18 'Sarah'.
!!  Exiting.
```

So, how do I **formally** change the edition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is stored in:

```
/etc/linuxmint/info
```

Just change this line:

```
EDITION="KDE 64-bit"
```

To the following:

```
EDITION="Cinnamon 64-bit"
```

---

Beware, that you will likely need to make this change one more time during the upgrade process, so be sure to have an SSH access to the machine.