# Correct preparation procedure before major system upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

What is the correct preparation procedure before:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

?

My current setting follows:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install --fix-broken

sudo apt-get update
```

I wonder if this is the right sequence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing, the HP engineers have it right, their *Pre-depend* steps when installing [`hplip`](http://hplipopensource.com) are:

[image: hplip pre-depend steps]

Under normal circumstances I don't recommend using `--yes` or `--force-yes`, though.

Re-writen from the image, without `--yes` and `--force-yes`:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install -f

sudo apt-get update
```